# How to transfer credentials to EC2 instances (non AWS creds)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, credentials

I have a scaling group of several `EC2` instances.
I have API keys which I would like to distribute to the instances using round-robin.

How can I code the instances to get the credentials once they go live?
Is there an `AWS` service for that?

**It is not AWS credentials which could be solved by defining IAM Roles.**

Thanks

Comment: Where do you have to send that key in the EC2 instance?

Comment: What do you mean?
The `EC2` instance need an API key in order to connect to a stream.
I do not want all instances to have the same API key. So I want each instance to contact a 3rd-party which serves as a API-pool.

Comment: You can define a script which will get the API key from the third party here http://imgur.com/a/QQ8pf which will be used by each EC2 instance at the time of launch. You can define this in the Launch configuration while creating the ec2 instance.

Comment: Can you supply some documentation on how to use this?

Comment: Check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts

Comment: Don't Amazon offer some kind of `secret store` service that can handle this elegantly?

Comment: There might be but one but but never got chance to look into that direction.

Comment: scaling group with a dynamic number of machines or a fixed number (read is min = max = desired?)?

Answer (score 0):

Use "user data" option when you start your EC2 instance,  You can run the bash script.

I recommend the following step.

1-put your cred or other shared information to S3 or dynamoDB.

2-write script to read and setting this data when your EC2 was starting.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing AWS has to this is called IAM Roles. A role includes a set of IAM permissions (like an IAM user). When you start a VM, you can set the role of the VM. The VM can then call the AWS API and get temporary credentials that give it access to the services that are defined in the IAM role.

See here for more details:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

This does not exactly meet your requirement for round-robin credentials distribution. But it might be a better option. IAM roles are as secure a method of distributing credentials to EC2 instances as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

AWS now provides two services that could be used for that purpose:

- The [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) would seem to be the most fitting, but does cost money from the start.
- The [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) is also an option and is free for up to 10k parameters.